# Migrating from Linux (Ubuntu, CentOS) to OS X (dev environment)

Tags: macos, unix, python

I'm about to migrate from Linux to OS X and I wonder if will encounter issues with development, as I probably will need lots of packages which are available in apt, yum package management systems. How can I find out whether these packages are available for OS X as well?

Comment: OS X has a package manager called [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). If you’re worried about whether a package will be available, probably best to start by seeing whether 1) it’s built-in, or 2) a Homebrew version is available.

Comment: Are ther available or is it possible to install epoll/libevent ?

Comment: @skzd Both of those are there.

Comment: @alexwlchan Feel free to post this as an answer :-)

Comment: I've edited your question to focus on one aspect, as multi-layered questions don't work very well here. Feel free to ask the other aspects in additional questions, but please consult the [FAQ] first to avoid overly broad questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a third-party package manager called [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), which is in fairly common use in the Mac development community. It’s very similar to apt or yum on Linux systems, and will have a lot of the same packages.

The easiest way to find out if a package is available is to Google for “brew <package name>” (as `brew install` is the installation command, not `homebrew install`), or to look through a list of Homebrew formulas like http://brewformulas.org.